# Android @TestApi Meaning

Tags: android, android-source

Hello I am working on AOSP. I see on many methods the symbol @TestApi. What does it mean?

Example:

```
/**
     * @hide
     */
    @TestApi
    public boolean isBound() {
        if (!mIsConnected) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Condition provider service not yet bound.");
        }
        return mIsConnected;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation :

> The stubs libraries are generated to include stubs, stubs.system, and stubs.test. These stubs libraries are created by recognizing @hide, @SystemApi, and @TestApi annotations. At build time, they are automatically referenced when the SDK version is current, system_current, and test_current, respectively.

[image: stubs diagram]

So stubs are generated based on the annotation and target api build - in this case "stubs.test"

source : https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/java-library